# NSIS: how to maintain subfolder structure when extracting to $InstallDir to equal the subfolder structure specified when I added files with File /r?

Tags: installation, nsis

I am adding files in my NSIS script that I want bundled with my installer exe.

Let's say I am adding files like this:

```
File myprogram.exe
File /r settingsdir\*.*
```

When the user installs, I want NSIS to respect the folder structure, not simply extract all the files to the current `$OUTDIR` or `$InstallDir`
So the extract will create a folder called `settingsdir` and extract all the `*.*` files it found on compilation to that sub folder `$InstallDir\settingsdir\`
How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
File /r settingsdir
```

is not the same as

```
File /r settingsdir\*.*
```

The latter includes a path where the search begins and `*.*` is searched for in that path at compile time.

Alternativly if you need a specific wildcard you can do

```
Push $OUTDIR
SetOutPath $OUTDIR\settingsdir
File /r settingsdir\*.foo
Pop $OUTDIR
SetOutPath $OUTDIR
```